# I'm getting this error over and over and I don't know how to fix it . Error (12002): Port "S[0]" does not exist in macrofunction "inst8"

Tags: quartus

I'm working in Quartus 2, trying to use a busmux to select the what to do, but when I click compile I just get this error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: how can i fix the problem?i mean the error that i'm getting when i compile.

Comment: So B0 to B3 come in individually to form bus B[3..0].  Are you sure SW[3..0] and SW[7..4] are coming in as a bus?  I have no knowledge of Quartus 2!

Comment: yes, but the problem is not there, the problem is in the entrance of the  BUSMUX,

Comment: what circuit is inside BUSMUX?